# How to populate and print an array in a struct from a file?

Tags: c

```
struct reviewStruct {
  char reviewer[50];
  int feedback[3];
};

int readReviews(FILE *file, struct reviewStruct reviews[10]) {

  int i;
  file = fopen("reviews.txt", "r");
  if (file == NULL) {
      printf("Error");
      exit(-1);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    fgets(reviews[i], 50, file);
  }
  return 0;
  fclose(file);
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%s", reviews[i]);
  }
}
```

> I'm trying to populate "struct reviewStruct reviews[10]" with information from a text file called "reviews.txt" I keep getting an error that says, "error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘fgets’" I'm not sure how to fix this, the output should be in the form \n \n and so on... How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. `fgets(reviews[i], 50, file);` -> `fgets(reviews[i].reviewer, 50, file);`
2. `printf("%s", reviews[i]);` -> `printf("%s", reviews[i].reviewer);`

Answer (score 0):

The declaration `struct reviewStruct reviews[10]` in the `readReviews` function declaration is creating an array of structs. in this call: `fgets(reviews[i], 50, file);`, you are passing a specific struct to `fgets()` which expects to be passed a string. Actually, you want to pass a certain element of the struct. Use the dot (`.`) operator to access a `struct`'s element. I assume you want your code to look like this:

```
struct reviewStruct {
  char reviewer[50];
  int feedback[3];
};

int readReviews(FILE *file, struct reviewStruct reviews[10]) {

  int i;
  file = fopen("reviews.txt", "r");
  if (file == NULL) {
      printf("Error");
      exit(-1);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    fgets(reviews[i].reviewer, 50, file);
  }
  return 0;
  fclose(file);
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%s", reviews[i].reviewer);
  }
}
```

I just replaced `reviews[i]` with `reviews[i].reviewer` to pass the `reviewer` string to the functions as opposed to the whole struct.